# JavaScript / Safari extension check application availability

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension, url-scheme

I built a Safari extension. It is made to open my native Mac app via a custom URL-Type.

Is it possible to check if the app I want to open is installed on the computer (can I open the URL `myapp://`)? Any idea on how I can accomplish this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Yes

Use window.location.assign("*URL*");

Comment: If I am correct this opens the app. I would like to check if it's installed (one can open my custom URL). I need a boolean if I can open it (without actually opening it)

Comment: see if it opens in a popup window with zero width and zero height